# Selenium script to detect presence of button and to click on it when it appears not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Python/coding newb, beware!

Im writing a script to download from youtube from " https://ytmp3.cc/en13/ ". I had written a click script using pyautogui but the problem being that the download button appears anywhere betweeen 1 and 15 seconds of entering the link. So i wanted to re-code it in a Selenium window to dynamically wait until the button is visible and then continue with the click script. I have tried about 15 ways but cant get it to work

library blah :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

**ways i tried to get it to work:**

without waits, results in NosuchElement Exception

```
   def check_exists():
        try:
            while True:
                a=driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Download")
                a.click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            time.sleep(10)
```

the syntax of this is most probably wrong
i tried a couple different variations of implicit and explicit waits but couldnt get it to work. Is there some javascript on the site linked above thats messing with my code?

in a separate .py, running

```
#driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Download").click()
#either the line above or below works at finding the element, and clicking it
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Download").click()
```

I just need help getting the line above ^ into an explicit wait, but i dont have the language knowledge of how to do it yet. i would appreciate some help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use webdriver wait to wait until button is displayed. Tried the below code which works for me

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

video_path = "your_video_path"
waitTime=10
driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://ytmp3.cc/")

element = driver.find_element_by_id("input")
element.send_keys(video_path)
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()

try: 
    # wait 10 seconds before looking for element 
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime).until( 
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT,"Download"))
    ) 
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Download").click()
finally: 
    print(driver.title)
```

You can update your required wait time in `waitTime` variable in seconds so if the value is 10 selenium will wait and check for elements upto 10 seconds